# How to catch multiple exceptions at once and deal with individual one, in Python?

Tags: python, exception

I understand you can do multiple exceptions handling in this way

```
try:
    pass

except EOFError:
    deals_with_EOFError()

except FileNotFoundError:
    deals_with_FileNotFoundError()
```

But, I wanted to know how it could be done through something like this

```
try:
    pass
except (EOFError, FileNotFoundError):

    if EOFError:
        deals_with_EOFError()
    else:
        deals_with_FileNotFoundError()
```

Comment: If for multiple exception you need different action, I suggest that your first approach is more than readable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use built-in `type()` to determine the type of the error object.

```
try:
    pass
except (EOFError, FileNotFoundError) as e:
    if type(e) is EOFError:
        deals_with_EOFError()
    else:
        deals_with_FileNotFoundError()
```

However, your initial example has better readability.

```
try:
    pass
except EOFError:
    deals_with_EOFError()
except FileNotFoundError:
    deals_with_FileNotFoundError()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `type()` function of python as follow:

```
try:
    # anything you have to do
except Exception as e:
    if type(e) == EOFError:
        # do what is necessary
    elif type(e) == FileNotFoundError
        # do what is necessary
```

This is because every exception in python is a child of built-in `Exception` class of python.

Comment: More succinct than other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the exception as `e` and then check whether it is equal to the desired one.

```
try:
    pass
except (EOFError, FileNotFoundError) as e:
    if type(e) == EOFError:
        deals_with_EOFError()
    else:
        deals_with_FileNotFoundError()
```